# Android : Populating a TextView with an INTEGER

Tags: android

Am writing an android code where a text view is being populated by a calculated % inside my java class.

As i had to calulate the %, my final variable (calcPerc) is a double type of variable. It wont setText into my TextView. 
Please help.

Code

```
int totDiff = (totalMA - totalIA);
    double beforeperc = ((double)totDiff / (double)totalIA);
    calPerc = ((double)beforeperc*100);

    percentage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.populatePercentage);
    percentage.setText(calPerc);
```

The error i am getting is

> The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (double)

Also, one more followup question. The variable "calPerc" as it is double, gives me infinite digits after the decimal. How do i round it off to 2 decimals only?

Comment: use Integer.toString(calPerc) to show int value in TextView

Comment: thanks! That worked. Can you tell me how to limit the number of decimals to only 2?

Comment: simple google search will get you answer. You have to use String.Value Of or just use what Krishna suggested above. The forum encourages searching for existing answers.

Comment: `as it is double, gives me infinite digits`. Really ? did we found a way to store infinite data in only 8 bytes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should format the value for display (with max 2 decimals) correctly for your current locale;

```
NumberFormat twoDecimals = NumberFormat.getInstance(); 
twoDecimals.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
percentage.setText(twoDecimals.format(calPerc));
```

Comment: thanks for answering with out any sarcastic comments. I am new to Android and this helped.

Comment: @Jasma Glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

To have more control over formatting (like limiting the number of digits after the decimal point), you can use `String.format()`:

```
percentage.setText(String.format("%.2f %%", calPerc));
```

But [be wary of the default locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#default_locale).

Comment: thanks! That worked. Can you tell me how to limit the number of decimals to only 2?